# Where did i do wrong when i tried to approximatee this data using polynomial?

Tags: matlab, numeric, numerical-methods

I am starting to learn numerical analysis using MATLAB in my course. so far we have covered polynomial interpolation (spline, polyfit, constraint spline, etc.) I was doing this practice question and I can not get the correct answer. I have uploaded the code I used and the question, where did I do wrong? thanks in advance!

```
close all; clear all; clc;
format long e

x = linspace(0,1,8);
xplot = linspace(0,1);
f = @(x) atan(x.*(x+1));
y_val = f(xplot);
c = polyfit(x,f(x),7);
p = polyval(c,0.7);
err = abs(f(0.7)-p)/(f(0.7))
```

The question I encountered is seen in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some playing around, it seems to be a matter of computing the absolute error instead of the *relative* absolute error.

The code below yields the desired answer. And yes, it is pretty unclear from the question which error is intended.

```
% Definitions
format long e
x = linspace(0,1,8)';
xplot= linspace(0,1);
f = @(x) atan(x.*(x+1));
y_val = f(xplot);

% Degree of polynomial
n = 7;

% Points to evaluate function
point1 = 0.5;
point2 = 0.7;

% Fit
c= polyfit(x,f(x),n);

% Evaluate
approxPoint1 = polyval(c, point1);
approxPoint2 = polyval(c, point2);

% Absolute errors
errPoint1 = abs( f(point1) - approxPoint1)
errPoint2 = abs( f(point2) - approxPoint2)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did wrong was :

1. mixing absolute and relative values when calculating errors to feed resulting variable `err`.
2. incorrectly placing `abs()` parentheses when calculating err: Your `abs()` only fixes the numerator, but then the denominator. To obtain |f(0.7)| you also need another `abs(f(0.7))`

for point `x=0.7` instead of

```
err = abs(f(0.7)-p)/(f(0.7))
```

could well simply be

```
err = abs(f(.7)-p));
```

3. you only calculate `err` for assessment point 0.5 . In order to choose among the possible candidates of what seems to be a MATLAB Associate test multichoice answer, one needs `err` on 0.5 and `err` on 0.7 and then match the pair in the correct order, among all offered possible answers.
4. Although it's common practice to approach polynomial approximation of `N` points with an `N-1` degree polynomial, it's often possible to approximate below satisfactory error with lower degree polynomials than `N-1`.

Lower degree polynomials means less calculations, less time spent approximating points. If one obtains a fair enough approximation with for instance a degree 4 polynomial, why waste time calculating an approximation with a higher degree all the way up to `N-1`?

Since the question does not tell what degree should have the approximating polynomial, you have to find it sweeping all polynomial degrees from 1 to up to a reasonable order.

5. The last error I found is that you have used linspace without specifying amount of points, MATLAB then takes by default 100 points hoping it's going to be ok.

Well, in your question 100 points is way too low an amount of points as I am going to show after supplying the following lines, as mentioned in previous point, sweeping all possible approximating polynomials, NOT on default 100 points you tacitly chose.

```
np=8;                                  % numel(x) amount supplied points
N=1e3;                              % amount points x grid we build to measure f(x)
x= linspace(0,1,np);

xplot = linspace(0,1,N);
f = @(x) atan(x.*(x+1));       % function to approximate
y_val = f(xplot);                   % f(x)

xm=[.5 .7];                         % points where to asses error

% finding poly coeffs

err1=zeros(2,np+2);          % 1st row are errors on x=.5, 2nd row errors on x=.7


figure(1);
ax1=gca
hp1=plot(xplot,y_val)
grid on;
hp1.LineWidth=3;
hp1.Color='r';
hold on


for k=1:1:np+2
    
c = polyfit(x,f(x),k);   

p_01 = polyval(c,xm(1));
err1(1,k) = abs(f(xm(1))-p_01);
% err(1,k) = abs((f(0.5)-p_05)/(f(0.5)))

p_02 = polyval(c,xm(2));
err1(2,k) = abs(f(xm(2))-p_02);
% err(2,k) = abs((f(0.7)-p_07)/(f(0.7)))

plot(x,polyval(c,x),'LineWidth',1.5); %'Color','b');

end

err1
```

.
[image]

.
[image]

The only pair of errors matching in the correct order are indeed those of polynomial order 7, but the total smallest error corresponds to the approximating polynomial of order 6.

What happens when taking `linspace` without defining a large enough amount of points? let's have a look:

```
np=8;                                  % numel(x) amount supplied points
% N=1e3;                              % amount points x grid we build to measure f(x)
x= linspace(0,1,np);

xplot = linspace(0,1); %,N);
f = @(x) atan(x.*(x+1));       % function to approximate
y_val = f(xplot);                   % f(x)

xm=[.5 .7];                         % points where to asses error

% finding poly coeffs

err1=zeros(2,np+2);          % 1st row are errors on x=.5, 2nd row errors on x=.7

figure(1);
ax1=gca
hp1=plot(xplot,y_val)
grid on;
hp1.LineWidth=3;
hp1.Color='r';
hold on

for k=1:1:np+2
    
c = polyfit(x,f(x),k);   

p_01 = polyval(c,xm(1));
err1(1,k) = abs(f(xm(1))-p_01);
% err(1,k) = abs(f(0.5)-p_05)/abs(f(0.5))

p_02 = polyval(c,xm(2));
err1(2,k) = abs(f(xm(2))-p_02);
% err(2,k) = abs(f(0.7)-p_07)/abs(f(0.7))

plot(x,polyval(c,x),'LineWidth',1.5); %'Color','b');

end

err1
```

[image]

With only 100 points all errors come up way too large, not a single error anywhere near 1e-5 or 1e-6.

This is why one couldn't tell which pair to go for, because all obtained values where at least 5 orders of magnitude away from landing zone.

I was about to include a plot with legend, but the visualization of this particular approach is in this case and in my opinion at best misleading, as in both plots for 100 and 1000 points, at 1st glance, both look as if the errors should be similar regardless of the amount of grid points used.

But as shown above 1e2 points cannot approximate the function,
it's like pitch dark, looking for something and pointing torch 180 from where we should be aiming at, not a chance to spot it.

Yet 1e3 grid points produce a pair of errors matching one of the possible answers, this is option D.

I hope it helps, thanks for reading my answer.

Comment: Lutz, to calculate an error one cannot place the abs() around the data, because that means modifying the data before comparing to the reference. After comparing data with reference then one applies abs() because when measuring errors often + or - is not as important than how far the measurement is departed from the expected reference. When doing that abs(y)-y0 as you point out the error calculation suffers bias. Error=|data-reference|.

Comment: dully noted, thanks for the correction. Because I was learning how to type code in the answer, and cut-paste ctrl+C ctrl+V was not working as expected, I typed the code manually in the answer field. The MATLAB script I used has the parentheses in the correct place and the resulting figures as well as the graph were all correct at the moment of submitting the answer. I give 1 point for your correction.

Comment: To your point 5.: The fit is always computed with the same `np=8` points of `(x,f(x))`, which are independent of the number `N` of points in xplot. Your argument of how to few points in `xplot` increases the measured error is incomprehensible, usually the error grows if you have more points to test. The code path to compute the `err1` array is the same in both scripts, there should be no difference in the values.

Comment: ((nitpick: while duty can be dull, to give something its due is to do it duly.))